# WooCommerce - Overriding wc-formatting-functions.php file via theme is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to include my code in **`wc-formatting-functions.php`** file when I am changing core file inside WooCommerce plugin folder, and it's working.

Now I have created **`woocommerce`** folder inside my theme folder and copied **`wc-formatting-functions.php`** file inside it, trying to override, but it's not working.

I am trying to insert this code inside **`wc_price()`** function:

```
if(is_product_category('mattress')){
    echo "mattress category";
}
else if(is_product_category('pillows')){
    echo "pillows category";
}
else if(is_product_category('protectors')){
    echo "protectors category";
}
else if(is_product_category('toppers')){
    echo "toppers category";
}
else if(is_product_category('foldable-mattress')){
   echo "foldable-mattress category";
}
```

just after these lines in wc-formatting-functions.php:

```
$formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $price_format, '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ) . '</span>', $price );
$return = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **`wc-formatting-functions.php`** is a **WooCommerce core** file and not a **template** file, You will not be able to make it work in a **`woocommerce`** folder inside your theme folder.

> **Is not possible to override `wc-formatting-functions.php` core file as a template file via a theme.**

Depending on where you want to use your code, you could try to use it in related hooks like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_price', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_price', 10, 2 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_price( $wc_price, $product ) { 
    // some code 
    return $wc_price; 
};
```

As `is_product_category()` conditional target category pages archives, you could override related woocommerce templates, depending on where you want to use your code.

You can even insert your code in function.php file of your active theme, embedded in a function that you could reuse.

But if you want to target a certain category with a conditional, you will have to use instead for example **`has_term( 'mattress', 'product_cat' )`** instead.

References:

- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [Function wc_price() in `includes/wc-formatting-functions.php`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#409)
- [Remove product content based on category with has_term()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/)

Comment: TheAztec  thank you very much for nice explanation..now i am trying to create hook so i can show images according to category.i am trying to use has_term( 'mattress', 'product_cat' ) but it is not showing anything on category page..

Comment: TheAztec can you please take a look on this question, I am having this problem. please..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567523/woocommerce-price-overriding-in-cart-dynamically

Comment: @websmentor.com Ok let me look at it… I will let you know in it.